# Building Tic-Tac-Toe Board and am stuck on an infinite loop. Any Suggestions?

Tags: java, netbeans, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to make the board display alternating X's and O's  on each square of the board and am having trouble not being able to stop the program from infinitely printing on the first space and switching markers. First I will show the class:

```
  public class Board {
    int cellsize = 4;
    int cellsperrow = 3;
    int rowsize = cellsize * cellsperrow;
    public final char[] marker = new char [] {'X'};
    public String boardRep = "___|___|___\n___|___|___\n   |   |   ";
    
    
    public final char [] [] board = new char[cellsperrow][cellsperrow];
    
    public Board(){
    for(int R = 0; R < board.length; ++R){
        for(int C = 0; C < board[R].length; ++C){
            board[R][C] = ' ';
        }
    }
  }   
    
    boolean IsEmpty(int row, int col){
        return board[row][col] == ' ';
    }
    
public boolean markBoard(char marker, int row, int col){
        if(!IsEmpty(row,col) || !isInRangeIndex(row,col)) {
            
    boardRep = boardRep.substring(0, row*rowsize) + boardRep.substring(row*rowsize,(row*rowsize) + (col*cellsize) + 1) + marker + boardRep.substring((row*rowsize) + (col*cellsize) + 2, boardRep.length());
        return false;
              
   }
    board[row][col] = marker;
    return true;
}
boolean isInRange(int V){
    return V >= 0 && V <= 2;
  }
boolean isInRangeIndex(int r, int c){
     return isInRange(r) && isInRange(c);
  }

    
}
```

This is the Main:

```
 Board B = new Board();
     char [] markers = {'X','O'};
     int marker = 0;
        
            
     int numRows = 3;
     int numCols = 3;
     
     
    for(int row = 0; row < numRows; ++row){
        
    for(int col = 0; col < numCols; ++col){
         
        while(true){ 
            
            System.out.println(B.boardRep);
            
            B.markBoard(markers[marker],row,col);
            marker = (marker + 1) %markers.length;
            
            
            System.out.println(B.boardRep);
            
            
      }
       
        

      }
    
     }
   }
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you! I apologize if this is not formatted right I am newer to this and have never used this website before.

Comment: I think your while(true){ needs an exit. Otherwise, it will not leave that block. You can test it by changing it to if(true) to be sure...

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation Charles! That stopped the infinite loop, but now my markers are no longer printing

Comment: reading through the markBoard, shouldn't

if(!IsEmpty(row,col) || !isInRangeIndex(row,col))

be checking that the cell is not empty AND is in range? The way its written it's an Exclusive OR, don't you want to mark the board on all cells regardless if its empty?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am struggling to put into code currently. Perfect wording

Comment: try it like 

if(isInRangeIndex(row,col)) {
 if(!IsEmpty(row,col)
 // do something
 // boardRep = boardRep.substring(0, row*rowsize) + boardRep.substring(row*rowsize,(row*rowsize) + (col*cellsize) + 1) + marker + boardRep.substring((row*rowsize) + (col*cellsize) + 2, boardRep.length());
)

Comment: That fixed it for me. Thank you for your help!